# How do I translate a rational inequality to an equivalent proposition, accounting for when it is undefined?

Tags: inequality, definition, propositional-calculus

In solving $\frac{5}{x-1}\le2$ I decided to translate it to an equivalent open proposition. It contains the two cases that result from multiplying both sides with something that could either be positive or negative:

$$P(x):(x-1\ne0)\land(((5\le2(x-1))\land(x-1\ge0))\lor((5\ge2(x-1))\land (x-1\le0)))$$

which eventually becomes

$$P(x):(x<1)\lor (x\ge3.5)$$

This translation was useful, but I wasn't sure if the initial translation was actually equivalent. If $x=1$, then the LHS of the inequality is undefined. Does this mean the truth value of the inequality is undefined, while false is the truth value of the proposition? That would mean they are not equivalent.

If I qualify the inequality so it becomes "$P(x):\text{ x is a solution to }\frac{5}{x-1}\le2$" that would definitely be equivalent, but do I need to in order for it to be? Could/should I write something like this?

$$P(x) \text{ when } x\ne1:(5\le2(x-1))\land(x-1\ge0))\lor((5\ge2(x-1))\land (x-1\le0)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{5}{x-1}\le2\iff x<1 \:\text{ or }\: x\geq3.5.$$

The atomic statement on the left of the above bi-implication is equivalent to the disjunction on its right.

In particular, both statements are false for $x=1:$ an undefined value is not at most $2.$